# Automatically ignore users in chat who have ignored me

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat

In chat, it is incredibly infuriating to find out that somebody is ignoring you after you've answered their questions, not knowing they simply aren't seeing it.

Please make it so that if you are ignored by somebody, you can't see them as well, or at least make it so you know you're being ignored to prevent lots of time wasted in attempts to communicate with them.

Comment: I agree. There's nothing worse than having someone ask a question and you try to help them, only to find out later they have you blocked. That doesn't do anyone favors.

Comment: Ah the many [problems of ignoring users](https://blog.codinghorror.com/your-community-door/)

Comment: Did someone post something?

Comment: @MartinJames and you'd never know if anyone tried to reply.

Comment: I don't think we should be building features around the many ways members of the JavaScript room get annoyed by each other....

Comment: @rene that's a poor reason. This could be a valid situation in any chat. No need to target the JS room like that.

Comment: I just want to know how many people are ignoring me so I can add up my k/d ratio.

Comment: @rene That was probably one of the most pointless and belittling statements I've seen on SO in some time. I'm sure there are many instances of people being blocked and not realizing it, we just happen to be able to know who's blocking us. Ignorance might be bliss, but in this case, it can do more harm than good.

Comment: Maybe not auto ignore, but hide their messages. If you auto ignore, then it's going to lead back to the same situation when one person un-ignores the other.

Comment: Why do users ignore people who answer their questions? What do they get out of that? (I get why people try to delete homework questions, even if it is bad behavior.)

Comment: presumably they ignored them at a point in time where they weren't answering their questions?

Comment: @BSMP people ignore for a magnitude of reasons. The issue happens when userA ignored userB a few weeks ago, userB is unaware, userA asks a question and userB spends 20 minutes talking to a brick wall.

Comment: We should probably just remove the chat ignore feature altogether.

Comment: @TylerH splendid!

Comment: or make it less of an ignore, and more of a... messages from said user are hidden behind a "click to show"

Comment: none of these solutions really fix the problem entirely though, you will still see others responding to some seemingly non-existent user. I've seen in other systems where you'd get a "This person is ignoring you", but that really only works if you're talking directly to that person, rather than openly in a chatroom.

Comment: @Trasiva sure, you can have that but I find it personally a little bit over the top to request a feature because you get infuriated when someone ignores you in a chat room. Come on, get real, go close some questions...

Comment: @rene or a recent transaction opened up peoples eyes to the flaws in a current system.

Comment: If this is to be done It would be nice to have it as a setting so you can opt-in or opt-out of it.  I for one do not want this and I would hate for it to happen automatically with nothing I can do to stop it.

Comment: Has anyone ever walked into the js room spontaneously?

Comment: @JonH you did..

Comment: @JonH I misclicked once, but got out before reading anything.  I'm told that, otherwise, it's like the Hotel California.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I agree that talking to someone who can't see your replies can be an annoying waste of time. Unfortunately, your solution to the problem probably causes more problems than it solves.

The ignore feature is strongly reminiscent of the [killfile feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_file) of Usenet readers. When there's another person in a conversation who, for whatever reason, brings out the worst in you, it's very helpful to silently block them. It breaks the thread of the conversation for you, but that's the cost of making a [Ulysses pact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulysses_pact). Unless you tell people you're ignoring someone, it's mostly harmless to others.

But where the feature becomes a problem is when the person ignoring someone else makes that fact public. On Usenet, it was common to publicly `*plonk*` trolls, which sometimes caused more noise than if everyone did the same thing quietly. Reciprocal ignoring would essentially build the plonk announcement into the system. That destroys the one positive feature of ignoring someone: reducing drama.

Comment: KevinB had a good point to simply hide them, not reciprocate the ignore. I feel that would be a better solution

Comment: @SterlingArcher: Yes, that's probably better. But it would break the conversation for people who get ignored. It wouldn't take much investigation to figure out who did that to you. (Pro-tip: you can read chat items from people you ignore in the transcript.)

Comment: I mean, the conversation is already broken if the person ignoring you isn't going to see you response. I'd rather shattered noise than pointless noise personally.

Comment: As a real-life example of the OP's suggestion: In Facebook groups, you are unable to see any comments or posts from someone who has you blocked. No Drama, no 'tit for tat' situations and no weird 'replying to nobody' issues. The only issue is one of Facebook's own bugs: members of a group can block admins, and effectively post stuff right under their noses making it hard to administrate a group without a sockpuppet account to check up on the group's wall. Here on SE, it would be trivial to eliminate that by bypassing the 'ignore' settings for diamond mods.

Comment: Even with an exception for mods it's not necessarily great, in that it gives me the ability to block you and then post something you might want to respond to or at least want to know that I've said it where the public can see it (e.g. it straw-mans your argument, or defames you, but not to an extent a mod would intervene). And you don't get to see it because my block of you is automatically reciprocal. A certain amount of mischief along these lines might still be preferable to the thing that Sterling is trying to avoid, talking to a brick wall.